# ML library to analyse UI patterns on a website?

Tags: machine-learning, scraping

now, this might be a bit of a stupid question (I’ve done a bit of data science / machine learning in my uni years but have gotten fairly er very rusty), but I’ll give it a go regardless. So, the idea should be rather simple: I’m looking to analyse the UI patterns on website. The context of this is [deceptive design / dark patterns](https://www.deceptive.design/types), so UI patterns that aim to mislead users (often to make them buy more). The idea is to eventually analyse the websites a user is seeing and pick out potentially deceptive patterns — but that’s a long way off, yet. I thought I’d start by building something that can „view“ a website (probably just auditing the rendered code?), segment all UI elements and analyse them in an easy way, probably just by classifying standard UI patterns (eg „this is a checkbox“).

How would I best go about that? Are there any libraries / toolsets around that give a head start?

Apologies for the rather vague post / help request. :)